# Do you need the $\sin(\phi)$ when you've changed to spherical coordinates and are trying to find a marginal probability distribution?

Tags: calculus, probability

I have a probability distribution function $f(\vec{x})=f(x,y,z)$, $\,\vec{x}\in\mathbb{S}^2$.

I want to get the marginal pdf of $f_\theta$ and $f_\phi$ after I've changed to spherical coordinates: $x=\sin\phi\cos\theta$, $y=\sin\phi\sin\theta$  and $z=\cos\phi$.

Do I have $f_\theta(\theta)=\int_0^\pi f(\phi,\theta)d\phi$ or do I need to include the $\sin\phi$ as when doing a surface integral on the sphere? i.e. $f_\theta(\theta)=\int_0^\pi f(\phi,\theta)\sin\phi\,d\phi$

I'm fairly certain it's the first one as we aren't doing a surface integral but I'd like to be sure! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am fairly certain it's the second one. Proof: You want the total integral to be the same regardless if you calculate it in Cartesian or spherical coordinates.

Comment: @KurtG. Ah yes that does make sense, thank you!